# Creating a package on Mathematica which will use the first derivative test

Tags: packages

This is what I have so far (I'm new at this sorry):

```
BeginPackage["FirstDerivativeTest`"]
firstderivative[f_, x_] = Module[{df, sol, point, dfleft, dfright},

    df:=D[f,x];
    sol=Solve[df==0,x];
    point={x,f}/.sol;

Do[
    dfleft=df/.x->point-1; 
    dfright=df/.x->point+1;


If[dfleft<0 && dfright>0, type="local minimum"];
If[dfleft>0 && dfright<0, type="local maximum"];
Print[ "there is a ", type  , " at ",point ,"."],
{point,point}]]

EndPackage[]
```

It gives me the points, but it won't tell me if it is a local maximum or local minimum. If there are any tips on how to get this Print to work correctly it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `point` a `List`? If so, what does `dfleft<0` mean?

Comment: @anderstood note that he used `point` as both the list and the iteration variable. Sam, best practice would suggest you don't do that. Also I don't think you need a `Print` call there. You can use `Table` and it will return values. I think you'll be best served by going to the tutorial materials Wolfram has created. I'll post an answer walking through what I think you want, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are a number of things here. First, find a good tutorial and read it. From the fact that you're using `BeginPackage` and `Print` statements I'm gonna guess you've used a different language before. Probably not python, either. Mathematica doesn't require that. We can just happily chug away in the front-end. (unless you're using Mathematica from the command-line, in which case you can just put this in a .m file).

Your question is really about, "how can I get `Do` to return values?", which has a very simple answer. Use `Table`. That's what it's built for.

So the code (plus tweaks) looks like this:

```
firstderivative[f_, x_] :=

 Module[{df = D[f, x], point, dfleft, dfright},
  point = x /. Solve[df == 0, x];
  Table[
   dfleft = df /. x -> p - 1;
   dfright = df /. x -> p + 1;
   Which[
    dfleft < 0 && dfright > 0,
    p -> "local minimum",
    dfleft > 0 && dfright < 0,
    p -> "local maximum",
    True,
    p -> "neither"
    ],
   {p, point}]
  ]
```

Then test it on a simply poly:

```
In[115]:= firstderivative[x^2, x]

Out[115]= {0 -> "local minimum"}
```

Note that we sometimes find odd things:

```
In[116]:= firstderivative[Sin, x]

Out[116]= {x -> "neither"}
```

That's because `Solve` doesn't return numbers, here, but rather an expression:

```
In[119]:= Solve[Cos[x] == 0, x]

Out[119]= {{x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(\[Pi]/2) + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[\[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

You'll have to get around that, but otherwise this should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much that was extremely helpful!

Comment: @sam Always glad to help.